# why main function run first in c/c++?

Tags: c++, c

Why main() function run first of all then other functions what if we want another function run first then main function in c or c++.
Can anyone explain logic behind it.thanks.

Comment: If you want another function to run first then call it at the start of `main()`.

Comment: You have programming background in interpreted languages, don't you? With this information, answers could compare to concepts you are used to.

Comment: In C++ isn't the constructor of global objects called before main?

Comment: @Osiris Yes it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because that's what the Standard defines the language to use (C++ quoted here):

> **[basic.start.main]**
>
> A program shall contain a global function called `main`. Executing a program starts a main thread of execution (...) in which the main function is invoked (...)

So the compiler has to produce the binary in a way that calls `main` when the program is started by the operating system, or, in case of freestanding environments, when it's loaded.

Technically speaking, it doesn't have to be the first `call` in the resulting assembly. The compiler can insert some additional startup code (like initializing variables etc.), which can itself be grouped into functions. This is out of concern of a C++ program developer, but becomes quite important on embedded systems, where you need/want to be aware of almost every instruction executed.

Answer (score 4):

A program has to start somewhere... As far as the developer is concerned that's typically `main()` - referred to as the "*[entry point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entry_point)*".

If you want to do certain things at the beginning of your program, then just move the content of your `main()` into another function (like `run()`), and place the startup code  in `main()` before calling `run()`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void init(void) {
    /* startup */
}

void run(void) {
    /* application functionality */
}

int main(void) {
    init();

    run();

    exit 0;
}
```

---

As far as the wider system is concerned there is an amount of setup that happens first:

- The process needs to be created (e.g: [`fork()`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_(system_call)))
- The stack needs to be prepared
- Global variables need to be initialized
- etc...

Answer (score 0):

This is because you can create *any* number of functions in a program.  You can have 1 function, 10, 2340 functions, or whatever.  The program needs to know where to *start*.  This is the purpose of the `main` function, as that is always the first function called.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a place in the program where the execution starts. In C it is function main.

But the program starts executing before the call to the main. That before `main` code prepares the execution environment for your program and it is called
 a startup code.